# Expectation of an exponentially distributed random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

The question is as follows:

Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, Find $\mathbb{E}[e^{sX}]$, where $s$ is a real parameter. For what values of $s$ does the expectation exist?

I understand how to find the expectation, but I am not sure exactly how to interpret the $\mathbb{E}[e^{sX}]$ part. I am only used to finding $\mathbb{E}[X]$, not the expectation of a composite function. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: In general, if $X$ has density $f$, then $E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f(x) \, dx$ ([LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)).

Comment: Thank you! @angryavian

Comment: This is the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function)

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\mapsto e^{sx}$ is a measurable function, we may use the law of the unconscious statistician to compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[e^{sX}] &= \int_{\mathbb R}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}e^{sx}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \lambda\int_0^\infty e^{(s-\lambda)x}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac\lambda{\lambda-s}.
\end{align}
Recall that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac1{1-z}$ for $|z|<1$. Writing $z:=\frac s\lambda$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac s\lambda\right)^n = \frac1{1-\frac s\lambda}= \frac \lambda{\lambda-s},
$$
and this series converges precisely when $s<\lambda$.